# In CouchDB, how to do database permissions affect replication?

Tags: security, couchdb

From the Wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview

Databases have "members" or readers, "admins" and "server admins"

Members can read, edit, and delete database documents except design docs. Admins can read, edit, and delete documents including design docs. Admins can also change the Members and Admins of the database for which they are Admins, change revision limits etc.
Server Admins can do all sorts of crazy stuff.

*the _users db is a special case, and it's awesome, works perfectly for my needs at least.

My concern is with replication.  As a db Member, what can I replicate to and form the database?  As a db Admin what can I replicate to and from the database?

I tried to experiment with replication and figure out on my own what "members" and "admins" could and could not do. It seems anyone who has permission to read a doc can replicate it, unless it's a design doc, then no one but the server admin is allowed to replicate it.  That last part seems wrong to me, and I off?

Comment: Read permission is not enough, you also need write permission to the destination database.

Comment: Ah, so since the database I was writing to was public, normal users couldn't replicate design docs to it, whether they were admins of the db I was replicating from or not. Awesome, that makes perfect sense!  

Question though, why couldn't I replicate normal json docs as a server admin?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Have you read http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication and https://gist.github.com/832610 (comments included)?

Comment: Yes, I've read that page of the wiki, I am not the most experienced developer in general though, maybe that's holding my understanding back.  So let me try to clarify.  When I was logged into Futon as _admin (the server admin) I tried to replicate from one db ('protected') to another ('public').  The protected db had a list of members and admins, the public didn't.  I was only able to replicate the design doc, but not any other docs.